# Old service worker won't let go

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I had a PWA a few years ago...  It worked reasonably well. I didn't know anything about service workers, but the react app came with one... and it seemed to let my app work offline. yay.

Now, I'm got a new version of the application -- started from scratch.  I have deleted all the v1 files from the webserver and uploaded all the v2 files. 
 I go the webserver at https://fakeurldomain.com and I get the old version... kind of as expected.

I hit refresh... old version.

I close the browser... load it back up... go to fakeurldomain.com ... get old version.

I press Ctrl+Shift+R for a hard refresh... NEW VERSION!!  yay!

Refresh the page... back to old version (NO!)

Reload browser... back to old version... (NO!)

What am I missing?

When I hit refresh while looking at the service worker in the dev tools, I see the following flash up: 
[image: Notice the "trying to install"]

I also get the following error... though I admit, I don't know if that error existed in the v1 of the software or not... [image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to **[unregister](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/unregister)** the old service worker.

I assume you did not include a new ServiceWorker script, like that one that comes with Create React App, with your v2 files, so the browser is still using your previously registered service worker.

For debugging, you can manually unregister a service worker in your browser developer tools, for example:

`Chrome DevTools > Application > Service Workers > Unregister`

However, previous visitors to your site will likely also have your page cached, so you should programmatically unregister the service worker.  This can be accomplished by finding and unregistering a registered Service Worker with **[ServiceWorkerContainer.getRegistration()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/getRegistration)**

```
navigator
    .serviceWorker
    .getRegistration()
    .then((serviceWorker) => {
        if (serviceWorker) {
            serviceWorker.unregister();  
    }})
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("There was an error: ", error);
    });
```

You can read more about Service Workers at the following link:  **[Service Workers: an Introduction](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers)**